# Почему встроенный firewall ubuntu пропускает запросы к порту?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

На Ubuntu LTS 20.04 через фаервол ufw запретил всех входящие соединения по умолчанию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
root@#########:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

В докере запускаю контейнер, который раздает страничку на 80 порту. По ip сервера удается достучаться до порта. Пробую явно заблокировать 80 порт через sudo ufw deny http, но запросы продолжают проходить. Iptables:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
root@#########:~# iptables -L | grep policy
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

Изначально цель была заблокировать всех входящие соединения и открывать порты **при необходимости ручным способом**, но теперь я уже сомневаюсь, что вообще что-то правильно настроено. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin исправил

Comment: Ну а из вне `nmap` чё говорит?

Comment: Лучше полный iptables покажите, не ограниченный grep. Ведь докер когда вы ему говорите показать порт наружу сам может добавлять в фаервол разрешающие правила

Comment: @Mike да, вы правы

Answer (score 0):

Docker при использовании -p добавляет запись в Iptables, поэтому игнорируется ufw.

Чтобы открыть порты только локально нужно Docker Linking или Docker Networks, либо открытие портов таким образом:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
```